# Ryan's bio description has a first/third person mixup

Tags: feature-request, bug, blog, wording

The [bio of Ryan Polk](https://stackoverflow.blog/author/ryan-polk/) contains mixed references to him, it's partly in first person and partly in third person:

> **Ryan is** Chief Product Officer at Stack Overflow. **My role** is to grow the product pieces of our work and set the site and the network on a path to build on the outstanding success of the first 15 years of the site.

It starts with third person view, which is common for other blog authors and expected, however then it suddenly switch to first person point of view.

This might not be wrong grammatically, but it's confusing and overall doesn't look good. Can it please be changed to one of those?

- Change "My role" to "His role", or
- Change "Ryan is" to "I am".

Comment: That is what you get with Ghostwriters ...

Comment: @rene so should we summon the Ghostbusters? :D

Comment: Never change Meta, never change.